# Memory Leak in WPF cause of System.Windows.Forms.Integration.AvalonAdapter

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, memory-leaks

Running ANTS Memory Profiler on my WPF application shows a path to memory leak which goes through `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.AvalonAdapter`:

GC...--> WPF User Control --> **System.Windows.Forms.Integration.AvalonAdapter** --> System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush --> System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage --> System.IO.MemoryStream --> System.Byte[]

Has anyone any idea about what this `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.AvalonAdapter` points to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you want to know? It is an internal class that is used by [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) and two other internal classes (`ElementHostAutomationPeer` and `ElementHostPropertyMap`).

Comment: My interest in this class is because of the fact that it comes in the path of garbage collection and results in memory leak.

Comment: I think you can be sure, that this class isn't the reason for the memory leak.

Comment: Has it something to do with appearance (like images and effects)?

Comment: Are you hosting your WPF user control inside a Windows Forms application?

Answer (score 1):

Weird nobody finished answering here.

Yes, if you host a wpf control in an ElementHost, AvalonAdapter will create a Bitmap for the background of the control. While this is not technically a memory *leak*, it does take up a surprising amount of memory (Bitmaps are heavy).

This doesn't happen if you're not hosting.

I haven't yet discovered if there's a workaround (other than stop hosting).